# How do I initialize Boolean values in a Spring configuration file?

Tags: java, spring

I have in fact searched for an answer to this, but have not found the solution. And, I am a complete Spring noob, and inherited this problem...

When I deploy the WAR file for my project, it fails citing a conversion from String to Boolean.  Details:

The Spring config file contains this (redacted) element:

```
<property name="logTypes">
    <map>
        <entry key="MESSAGE" value="${xxx.messagelogenabled}" />
        <entry key="SUMMARY" value="${xxx.summarylogenabled}" />
        <entry key="STATISTICS" value="true" />
        <entry key="ERROR" value="true" />
        <entry key="WARNING" value="true" />
        <entry key="DEBUG" value="${xxx.debuglogenabled}" />
    </map>
</property>
```

The "xxx.*logenabled" strings are defined as either "true" or "false" elsewhere, but this fails even when I replace those references with "true".

The setter for the "logTypes" property is:

```
public void setLogTypes(Map<String, Boolean> logTypesMap)
{ /* I think the problem is with Spring creating the argument
     to this method, not the method itself */ }
```

I am getting the following runtime error that fails the deployment:

```
Error setting property values;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException;
nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
   PropertyAccessException 1:
      org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [java.util.Map] for property 'logTypes';
      nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

Here is the version of Java I am running:

```
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This is disturbing - when I run Tomcat under Java 1.6 and the problem goes away. I had read the incompatibility lists betweeen 6/7 and7/8 and did not see anything that seemed to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see here as 1 more way which work on type cast
Use java code to

```
<property name="MESSAGE" value="#{T(java.lang.Long).parseLong('${xxx.messagelogenabled}')}" />
```

This works for me fine.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify key type and value type for map

```
<property name="logTypes">

    <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Boolean">

        <entry key="MESSAGE" value="${xxx.messagelogenabled}" />
        <entry key="SUMMARY" value="${xxx.summarylogenabled}" />
        <entry key="STATISTICS" value="true" />
        <entry key="ERROR" value="true" />
        <entry key="WARNING" value="true" />
        <entry key="DEBUG" value="${xxx.debuglogenabled}" />
    </map>
</property>
```